# How to hide heredoc block in ruby-mode?

Tags: ruby-mode

In ruby-mode, using hs-minor-mode (hideshow) you can hide almost any block of code, but heredocs.

I've tried adding "LONG_HEREDOC" to hs-special-modes-alist, but it didn't worked:

```
(eval-after-load "hideshow"
  '(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
                 `(ruby-mode
                   ,(rx (or "def" "class" "module" "{" "[" "do" "<<LONG_HEREDOC")) ; Block start
                   ,(rx (or "}" "]" "end" "LONG_HEREDOC"))                       ; Block end
                   ,(rx (or "#" "=begin"))                        ; Comment start
                   ruby-forward-sexp nil)))
```

I think it has todo with "ruby-forward-sexp". It doesn't seem to work with heredoc comments.

Does any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
(require 'hideshow)

;; Set up hs-mode (HideShow) for Ruby
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             `(ruby-mode
           ,(rx (or "def" "class" "module" "do")) ; Block start
               ,(rx (or "end"))                       ; Block end
               ,(rx (or "#" "=begin"))                ; Comment start
               ruby-forward-sexp nil))

(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'hs-minor-mode)

(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f9>") 'hs-hide-all)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<f9>") 'hs-show-all)
```

Stolen from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Karina7777/e6207b027af0b391ff38).

Comment: It would be better to provide instructions/code rather than a bare link which will easily go out of date.

Comment: I don't think this answer even includes heredocs at all, unless I'm missing something, so I don't know why this answer received any votes.